# roslibpy : Publishing and subscribing using custom messages

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

are there some examples which could guide me to publishing and subscribing using custom messages with roslibpy ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304574/roslibpy-:-publishing-and-subscribing-using-custom-messages/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-10-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-10-01**:
@gramaziokohler @gonzalocasas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For completeness, the question is answered in detail in [this github issue](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy/issues/11#issuecomment-428178646), but in short: you don't need to add any additional type information, simply supply a message -which is basically a python dictionary- that matches (key and value-type-wise) to the expected message format and that's it.

---

Originally posted by [gonzalocasas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34021/gonzalocasas/) with karma: 180 on 2019-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dwd394](https://answers.ros.org/users/108750/dwd394/) on 2022-07-12**:
excellent answer my guy